# Get total count of the filtered field's sizes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
user_number: {
    $add: [
        $size: {
            '$schedules.users': {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$schedules',
                    as: 'schedule',
                    cond: {
                            $and: [
                                    {
                                    $gte: ['$$schedule.schedule_info.schedule_time', start_date]
                                    },
                                    { $lte: ['$$schedule.schedule_info.schedule_time', end_date] }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
```

I want to return the total number of users that are attending to the schedule that filtered events. Each document's `schedules.users` field is an array that contains `user names`. How can I get the total number of users that are part of the filtered schedules?

I can get the total number by using `$add` and the total number of users attending the schedule by `$size`. However, I am stuck on putting them together with the `$filter`.

Edit:

```
 {
      schedules: [
         {
         name: 'gaming events',
         date: '2021-01-14 07:00:00.000Z'
         attendee: [
            'john',
            'jane',
            'joe',
            'dow',
        ],
      },
      {
         name: 'GTA events',
         date: '2021-01-15 07:00:00.000Z'
         attendee: [
            'john',
            'Tina',
            'joe',
        ],
      },
      {
         name: 'gaming events',
         date: '2021-01-19 07:00:00.000Z'
         attendee: [
            'john',
            'jane',
            'joe',
            'dow',
        ],
      },
     ],
      calcDistance: 1643.3598155320283,
    },
```

- Filtering schedule with the given date.
- Returning the total number of attendees from filtered schedules.

If I filtered the schedules with "2021-01-14 to 2021-01-15", then it will be 4 + 3 = 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$filter` schedules on the base your date condition in first stage
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `schedules.attendee` and get total count and size of the `attendee` using `$add` and `$size`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      schedules: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$schedules",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              { $gte: ["$$this.date", start_date] },
              { $lte: ["$$this.date", end_date] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalAttendees: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$schedules.attendee",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: { $add: [{ $size: "$$this" }, "$$value"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lqmGdJTXbvA)